# setup.py build doesn't work but develop does

Tags: python, setup.py

I have a simple python package that's importable without issue when running:

`python setup.py develop`

but not when running

`python setup.py install`

No error occurs* when running install but I get a `no module named...` error when I attempt to import it even though I can see the package when I run `pip list`. I only have python 2.7 installed, I'm not using virtualenv, so I don't understand why `develop` works but `install` doesn't.

(additionally running `build` then `install` also fails)

---

**No error but a *warning I couldn't find details about...**
[image]

---

**Listed but importing will fail**
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `python setup.py develop --uninstall` before attempting to install?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting this issue now.

Answer (score 1):

Posting about this since it affected me. The important thing to know is that distutils which builds the package builds it *even though it has broken dependencies*, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages). If you watch the output when you run `python setup.py install` you will probably identify the source of the problem.

For me, I had a package called "whatever" with a full name that was very clear what it was, but is annoying to type. So I wanted the command itself to be an abbreviation, like "we".

Orginally, my setup.py looked like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='we',
    version='3.0.3',
    py_modules=['we'],
    install_requires=[
        ...
    ],
    scripts=['whatever/bin/we']
)
```

Where my folder structure was like this:

```
├── setup.py
├── whatever
│   ├── bin/
│   │   ├── we
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── other_stuff/
```

and inside `we`, I import the full package (that has a click interface):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from whatever.cli import cli
cli()
```

When I ran the install I saw this:

```
$ python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing we.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to we.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to we.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to we.egg-info/top_level.txt
file we.py (for module we) not found
reading manifest file 'we.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'we.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
file we.py (for module we) not found
file we.py (for module we) not found
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
...
```

The problem was that there was no *module* named we, only the cli tool. Removing the `py_modules` line and replacing it with `packages` pointing the full *package* folder name solved it for me:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='we',
    version='3.0.3',
    packages=['whatever'],
    install_requires=[
        ...
    ],
    scripts=['whatever/bin/we']
)
```

Now when I run `we`, the whatever cli package executes. Hope this helps any future readers.